# Why Does a Label Inside an Input Trigger a Click Event

Tags: jquery, html

If I have an `input` inside a `label`, why does every word in the sentence trigger a click event?

Here is a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d3pcs/)** for an example. No matter what word you click on in the first sentence, the event is fired.

I added some CSS on the `input` so you can see that no matter where in the first label you mouse over, it's like you are hovering over the input. I also added a second label using an `a` tag inside the `label` which works as I would expect the `input` to work (the click event does not fire when you click on a word in the label).

```
<label>Click <input type="submit" value="here" /> to go somewhere.</label>
<label>Click <a href="#">here</a> to go somewhere else.</label>

$('input, a').click(function() {
    alert('Clicked');
});
```

My two questions are:

1. Is there a way to use an `input` inside a `label` in a way that the `label` does not trigger the click event?
2. In my example, why does the click event fire on every word in the sentence?

Comment: labels target form elements, for example clicking a checkbox label, will toggle the relevant checkbox. Labels are usually "linked" to the relevant form element with a for attribute.

Comment: This is how labels interact with inputs, I don't think you can change this behavior. Typically clicking on the label focuses on the related input.

Comment: Dude, I have not clue. I hope someone can answer this. I'm been messing with a fiddle for 5 mins trying to figure it out. Only thing I can think is that you're right, inputs buttons don't play well as children of labels. I know they are supposed to be for the input, but I don't know why an onclick event would link.

Comment: @Jack yeah it annoyed me enough that I just had to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the help/explanations everyone!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is part of the HTML spec - `label` elements increase the hit area of the related `input`. You can handle the click yourself and `preventDefault()`, however it will not stop the button UI changing on click.

```js
$('input, a').click(function() {
  console.log('Clicked');
});

$('label').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  Click <input type="submit" value="here" /> to go somewhere.
</label>
<label>
  Click <a href="#">here</a> to go somewhere else.
</label>
```

Alternatively you could change the `label` elements to `span` with the appropriate styling to make them behave the same way, although you will be hurting your users' experience.

Comment: Is there a way to to stop the button UI from changing? Sorry, I'm just curious.

Comment: I've not tried it, but I would highly doubt it as that is controlled by the browser itself and is a level below the control of JS.

Comment: Just as an side (and because I was interested), using `label for=""` has the same affect as putting the input in the label. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6MH52/1/)

Comment: Thanks. Solved a problem with the event, triggered twice, I realized that it was the event attached to the label, not the input